# Using std::tuple_element<>::type is being flagged as always false when used in another type_traits checker in a fold expression

Tags: c++, c++17

I am playing around with template packing, so I chose to make a function that checks if a list of numbers are all equal to zero. This is what I came up with.

**Note: All code examples are tested on Coliru with its default values of:**
`g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr T EPSILON = 0.000001;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_zero(const T t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
        return -EPSILON<T> < t && t < EPSILON<T>;
    } else {
        return t == 0;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
constexpr bool is_zero(const T t, const Ts... ts) {
    return is_zero(t) && is_zero(ts...);
}
```

This worked as expected.

Because I'm trying to use C++17 features and learn them, I tried using (or rather, adding and replacing) this:

```
#include <tuple>

// ...

template <typename ...T>
constexpr bool is_zero(const T... t) {
    using firstType = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<firstType>::value) {
        return ((-EPSILON<T> < t and t < EPSILON<T>) and ...);
    } else {
        return ((t == 0) and ...);
    }
}
```

In all my test cases, the above works... however my compiler/IDE is complaining that the line

```
if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<firstType>::value) {
```

is always false.

Since the application tells me that I am in fact branching in (and thus the warning is wrong, the value is true for the `float` type), then the warning appears to be incorrect.

However I am afraid to say "my IDE is wrong" because there have been many times in the past where I thought that was not the case only to find out upon further research that it was right and I was in fact wrong. I am afraid to make that mistake again.

Am I correct this time in saying my IDE is highlighting it wrong, or have I missed something and the warning has some legitimate corner case I have missed?

Or is my fold expression/template code wrong?

Comment: Your second variant of code does not do what you want for is_zero(0, 0.00000001), regardless of the IDE warning.

Comment: your code seems OK to me

Comment: Also is_zero(0.0, 0) will return false. Note that firsType is double, selecting the `then` part. But for the second parameter `EPSILON<int>` is `int(0.000001)` which is zero, hence `((-EPSILON<T> < t and t < EPSILON<T>)` is `0 <0 and 0<0`